# In excel, is there a way to generate a random code based off of a word/string set?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm aware of ASCII values and the Char(Randbetween) function in Excel. I'm curious if it's possible to make a random code/password based of the contents of another cell, or would the function have to be incredibly specified.

```
For example, lets say in Cell A1 I have the word 'WINDOWS'.
In cell A2 I want to generate a random code based of the contents of A1 like 'DWS','WOD', or 'SWI' for example.
```

Comment: Yep, you just need some VBA.

Comment: You could try this in A1: `=MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)),1)&MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)),1)&MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)),1)`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),RANDARRAY(LEN(A1))),3),1))
```

Or, without `TAKE()` if not yet available:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(MID(A1,SORTBY(SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),RANDARRAY(LEN(A1))),1)),3)
```

This would ensure that the random generated string takes three letters from `A1` in random order without taking the letter from the same index/position more than once.

For your understanding, change `3` to any number up to the length of the original input and see how the random code will generate a longer/shorter password.

Note that `RANDARRAY()` is volatile and will recalculate upon any change to the worksheet made.

Comment: That is very cool. I'm pretty good with Excel, but I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Formula in A2"?

Comment: @Ike, absolutely